# SimpleForms - email not send

Tags: bolt-cms

SimpleForms is not sending any emails. I turned off the test mode, and did not change the mail settings in the config.yml file:

```
# by default, mail is sent using PHP's built-in mail function. In general, it's advised to use SMTP for sending mail
# instead. Uncomment the following lines to use an SMTP server with authentication.
# Please check http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/swiftmailer.html for a full range of options
#mailoptions:
#  host: localhost
#  port: 25
#  username: username
#  password: password
#  encryption: null
#  auth_mode: null
```

So bolt should use PHP's mail function. On the same server I have several Drupal installations sending emails correctly. The error log doesn't contain anything relatied to mails.

What am I doing wrong? And are there any logs from bolt?

Edit: My simpleforms.bolt.yml:

```
[...]

recaptcha_enabled: false
recaptcha_public_key: ''
recaptcha_private_key: ''
recaptcha_error_message: "The CAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Please try again."
recaptcha_theme: clean

csrf: true

from_email: [...]
from_name: Anonym

testmode : false
testmode_recipient: [...]

contact:
  recipient_email: "[...]"
  recipient_name: "[...]"
  mail_subject: "[...]"
  button_text: "Senden"
  fields:
    name:
      type: text
      required: true
      placeholder: Ihr Name
      label: Name
    email:
      type: email
      label: E-Mail-Adresse
      required: true
      placeholder: Ihre E-Mail-Adresse
    subject:
      type: text
      required: true
      placeholder: Betreff Ihrer Nachricht
      label: Betreff
    message:
      type: textarea
      required: true
      placeholder: Ihre Nachricht
      label: Nachricht
```

Comment: what are the settings for your form?

Comment: added settings of the form

Comment: the recipient_mail does not need quotes, but otherwise the config looks okay. if you turn debug on in the simpleforms configuration a lot of info will be visible in your rendered page ( debugmode: true )

Answer (score 1):

As I didn't get the extension to work by myself, I finally asked on the IRC channel. I was told that the documentation is wrong. Bolt always uses Swiftmailer for sending mails even if "mailoptions" is commented-out completely.

By default Swiftmailer does not output much information. That's why I always got a success message on sending, but nothing happened. As Bolt version 2.1 already is in feature-freeze, the Swiftmailer output is improved not until version 2.2.

I now configured my mailoptions according to the "phpinfo()" information (simply using "localhost" and "25" as "host" and "port") and then got the form sent correctly.

Comment: So you use a SMTP server? That's the only solution I found, too.

Comment: newer versions of bolt (2.1.4 and up) will warn you to set your mailoptions if you have installed simpleforms or any other extension that needs mail

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with mail not being sent. 
Then I ran into the config.yml of the latest version which says, to enable your notifications in your form:

```
notification:
    enabled: true
    debug: false
    debug_address: name@example.com # Email address used when debug mode is enabled
    debug_smtp: true
```